# Apply custom option price once regardless of quantity

Tags: magento

I need to sell business cards in Magento. If the customer wants to use metallic ink (gold or silver) then I need to add $60 to the order, regardless of the quantity. I currently have Metallic Ink as a custom option, but Magento applies the $60 to each item. So if they order 100 business cards (which costs $25) there's an extra $1,500 added, making the total cost $1,525. The cost should be $85. How can I do this?

I've found Magento extensions that can do this, but one is $135 and one is $165. That seems a bit ridiculous to accomplish something that should be so simple for an online store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create an option for 100 cards, 250 cards, 500 cards etc and not allow the user to input the product qty but select it just like the ink option. This would stop people from ordering random number of cards like 37! Your problem is that magento takes the inputted qty and multiplies it by price (including options). If you remove the qty field (i.e so it always 1 when they click add to basket) and make the qty an option it allows for control over order volumes, discounts and surcharges like you are trying to achieve for free. Otherwise the quoted module prices seem very reasonable...

I would;

- Create custom option for qty of cards with fixed prices for each
  band.
- Custom option for ink type with fixed price.
- Remove or hide the
  qty field on product page and cart.

Comment: Thanks, I think that could work. Wouldn't creating a configurable product for this be better though? Meaning create a configurable product called "Business Cards" and then create simple products for each quantity ("Business Cards-100" and "Business Cards-200"). That should work also, right?

Comment: Yep, there are several ways to do this with the standard setup of magento, play with them to see which method suits your needs best.

Comment: Ok, thanks. That should take care of the problem. I need to wait 16 hours to award the bounty...

Comment: If you go the configurable product route you will want to set the Business Cards-100, Business Cards-200 etc to Not Visible in catalog and search. Advantage is it gives you an SKU for the qty selection but you get lots of products in database. For a simple site with small product database it's not a problem, but can be confusing when there are lots of them.